# Join and compare data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables PROJECT and TIMESHEET in the same schema name and two columns allocation_days(integer) from PROJECT and allocation_time(integer) FROM TIMESHEET.All I want to do is to join those two columns and make a short verification something like this:

```
SELECT Project.ID, Project.allocation_days, Timesheet.allocation_time
FROM Project

INNER JOIN Timesheet
ON Project.ID=Timesheet.ID;

DECLARE @hours int

SET @hours = SELECT SUM(allocation_time) from PROJECT

IF (@hours /24) < allocation_days 

    --insert something

 ELSE 

    BREAK

ENDIF
```

but I don't know the order of conditions to get the insertion if is <24 or break.
Thanks.

Comment: so, is it SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server I forgot to specify..

Comment: just remove the `MySQL` tag

Comment: @Alienware No, you did specify it by using the SQL Server tag, but you also added the MySQL tag. Please, don't add tags that aren't related to the question

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I really cannot follow what you want to do.  What are you trying to insert into?  What is the comparison really doing?

Comment: The comparison is checking if a number divided by 24 is greater or smaller than allocation_days which is in days, this is  all you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single query like

```
select *,
case when SUM(allocation_time) / 24 < allocation_days then 'Something' 
else 'some_other_thing' end as computed_column
from
(
SELECT Project.ID, Project.allocation_days, Timesheet.allocation_time
FROM Project
INNER JOIN Timesheet
ON Project.ID=Timesheet.ID;
) tab
GROUP BY ID, allocation_days, allocation_time
```